# ng-class button stops working after using its activator with a link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this

```
  body
    div(ng-class="toggle ? 'nav-open' : 'nav'")
      .container
        .logo
          img(src='images/logo.png')
          span Motto
        ul(ng-class="toggle ? 'menu-open' : 'menu'")
          li
            a(href="#!/", ng-click='toggle = !toggle') Home
          li
            a(href="#!/products", ng-click='toggle = !toggle') Products
```

activated first by this

```
  button.upon(type="button", ng-click='toggle = !toggle') Menu
```

and you see it closes clickin on a link. The problem is that when I close it by a click it doesnt' work anymore, must refresh the page in order to do it, and using this while on mobile it just closes without changing the page. What am I doing wrong and/or is there any better way to achieve what I'm doin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out some of the examples in the docs - there's a few different ways to use ngClass. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

I think this syntax should probably work for your case:

```
ng-class="{'nav-open': toggle, 'nav': !toggle}"

ng-class="{'menu-open': toggle, 'menu': !toggle}"
```

Essentially you're providing ngClass with a configuration object that says: 
"Apply the `nav-open` class when `toggle` is `true`, and apply the `nav` class when `toggle` is false".

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it for sure, but I have to say you that it worked automagically after I added css styles for mobile/desktop to the button, I don't know why.